# Как настроить Docker на сервере

Tags: docker

Есть контейнер на докере. Докер на виртуальном сервере. На этот сервер могу подключится по адресу а.б.с.д

На локальном сервере внутри этого самого докера(через teamviewer) по адресу у.у.у.у открывается контейнер-сайт... Но проблема в том что по статическому адресу а.б.с.д он не открывается... Где копать? Что настроить?

UPD: сервер на Ubuntu

Comment: по сути мне нужно настроить сеть таким образом чтобы при потключении к а.б.с.д сервер открывал у.у.у.у  - некий алиас....но я не знаю как это делать

Comment: Что-то [вроде этого](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/)?

Comment: похоже,но я не знаю должен я это делать внутри контейлера или вне

Comment: я убедился что это нужно делать вне....но всеравно...до меня не особо все это доходит...я и на той странице тоже копался....я думаю может я уже ччтото испортил..

Comment: та статья не помогла...я так и не понял что нужно делать

Comment: *по статическому адресу а.б.с.д он не открывается* — как «открываете» и что при этом происходит?

Answer (score 0):

Сам нашел способ.  Установил nginx. И через прокси направил на адресс созданный докером